# No visible Dialog in MockedUI while Karibu Unit Testing

Tags: kotlin, unit-testing, vaadin

I am coding in Kotlin. I am trying to migrate my project from Vaadin 22 to Vaadin 23.3. I am using Karibu Testing 1.3.23 for Vaadin Unit Testing.

When I try to: `val dialog = _get<Dialog>()` in my unit tests, I get the following error: `java.lang.AssertionError: /: No visible Dialog in MockedUI["<description_of_mocked_UI>"] matching Dialog: [].`.

From my investigation so far, I understood that my Unit Tests throws an Assertion Error at the the following Karibu function: `public fun <T: Component> Component._find(clazz: Class<T>, block: SearchSpec<T>.()->Unit = {}): List<T>` after a certain number of iterations.

Any ideas about this? This is my first time working on Karibu Testing, and I have been stuck for a week now.

Comment: Just to be clear here: your test worked with 22 and now it fails
with above error in 23?

Comment: Yes. In Vaadin 22, the project was running perfectly. As soon as I switched to Vaadin 23.3 a lot of errors started happening, and I was correcting here and there, until I was stuck at this unit testing error for more than a week.

Answer (score 1):

that's strange. You're using the correct Karibu-Testing version, so that part is okay. When `_get()` fails, it will dump the entire component tree nested in the UI. Do you see the dialog in the dump please? It should be attached as a direct child of `MockedUI`.

Without further information I can only guess, but here are a couple of tips:

- `_get<Dialog>()` should find a Dialog if it's attached to the UI. That happens after you call `dialog.open()`. Perhaps `dialog.open()` was not called for some reason?
- Also, please note that `ConfirmDialog` is not a `Dialog`, so if looking up `ConfirmDialog` you need to call `_get<ConfirmDialog>()` instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 1. I am not calling `dialog.open()` because the error is happening at the level of `val dialog = _get<Dialog>()`. 2. I am not using `ConfirmDialog`. I Am using a normal `Dialog`. 3. Here is a link for my `MockedUI` tree: https://docs.google.com/document/d/15HL0VaclD0TpCkY_HLEXiyOXzq_Nt_0k_nLuEmC0fsU/edit?usp=sharing As you can see, it is not containing dialog.

Comment: Yeah there's no Dialog in the UI tree dump. The Dialog needs to be open in order to appear in the UI tree; `_get<Dialog>()` looks up components from the current UI tree.

Comment: I don't get it. `val dialog = _get<Dialog>()` is the first line of my unit-test. How come everything is created in MockedUI but Dialog? Also, how would I call `dialog.open()` before doing `val dialog = _get<Dialog>()`?

Comment: I found out new information that is more related to Vaadin 23.3 rather than Karibu Testing. Feel free to check this Discord thread on Vaadin's server: https://discord.com/channels/732335336448852018/1128977300730413156. Thank you. I feel that I am very close to a solution now.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this issue but I was running integration tests and I was using custom `TestingLifecycleHook`.
The solution I found was to add `MockVaadin.clientRoundtrip();` before  `_get()`.

Dialog attaches itself lazily by default, and `clientRoundtrip()` forces eager attachment. You can refer my issue [here](https://github.com/mvysny/karibu-testing/issues/166)