# Migration failing from Vaadin 22 to Vaadin 23.3

Tags: java, gradle, migration, vaadin, vaadin-flow

I am trying to migrate my Kotlin-based project from Vaadin 22 to Vaadin 23.3.

When I finished setting up versions for my build.gradle.kts, I received the two following errors:

### First Error:

[image]

I fixed this error by changing `ComponentEventListener<GeneratedVaadinDialog.OpenedChangeEvent<Dialog>>` to `ComponentEventListener<Dialog.OpenedChangeEvent<Dialog>>`.

### Second Error:

[image]

I fixed this error by changing `open class GaliteVUITestBase: VUITestBase(), TestingLifecycleHook {` to either `open class GaliteVUITestBase: VUITestBase(), TestingLifecycleHook by TestingLifecycleHookVaadin14Default() {` or `open class GaliteVUITestBase: VUITestBase(), TestingLifecycleHook by TestingLifecycleHookVaadin23_1(TestingLifecycleHook.default) {`, since the first fix is for all Vaadin versions, and the second one for Vaadin 23.1 (or more (?)).

To be honest with you guys, the changes seemed logical to me, but I am still unable to get my project to work. (It was obviously working completely fine in Vaadin 22).

If I try to build my project using:

```
./gradlew clean build --refresh-dependencies
```

I get assertion errors in my unit tests ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76689430/no-visible-dialog-in-mockedui-while-karibu-unit-testing)).

And if I try to run my project in localhost using:

```
./gradlew vaadinPrepareFrontend vaadinBuildFrontend run
```

I get **Whitelabel Error Page** in my localhost.

This is my first Kotlin/Vaadin experience, and I have been stuck with this for more than two weeks now. I would appreciate any kind of help or track. Thank you.

#### Notes:

- Operating System: Fedora 38
- IDE: IntelliJ IDEA
- Project Builder: Gradle
- Java Version: 11
- Vaadin Version: 23.3.0
- Unit Testing Tool: Karibu Testing
- Karibu Version: 1.3.23
- Enhanced Dialog Version: 23.0.0

Comment: I have a hard time to follow, what you are actually asking: you fixed two compile problems and you are not sure, if its a proper fix (close-worthy - SO wants you to create single-focus questions). Next you are pointing us to another question (so is this a duplicate? Close-worthy...).  And finally you state, that you get a "Whitelabel Error Page" - which shows a stacktrace (and most likely logs a stacktrace) - so why not add this error here and correlate it with some code snippets and remove all the unrelated things here.  And if this helps to answer your other question, then add it there.

Comment: Sorry if this was unclear. I tried my best to make it as clear as possible. Basically, when I tried migrating my project from V22 to V23.3, I got two compile errors. I fixed them, but I was still unable to build/run my application, so I am wondering if my fixes are correct or not. If they are correct, then what may be the issue of the build/run failure? If they are incorrect, what is the correct fix?

Comment: Please add the stacktrace from the whitelabel error you get and correlate it to the code.